# java.lang.NullPointerException at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2111)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, servlets

Eclipse error report:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2111)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:189)
at de.mail.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:33)
at de.mail.gui.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:55)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Browser/Tomcat error report:

exception

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
```

root cause

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
de.mail.gui.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:55)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

root cause

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2111)
org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:189)
de.mail.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:33)
de.mail.gui.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:55)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

I am using spring with hibernate, the context.xml looks like this:

```
<bean id="c3p0DataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="something" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="1" />
    <property name="properties">
        <props>
            <prop key="user">postgres</prop>
            <prop key="password">something</prop>
            <prop key="characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<alias name="c3p0DataSource" alias="dataSource" />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    <property name="nestedTransactionAllowed" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" destroy-method="destroy">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>                
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="annotatedPackages">
      <list>
        <value>de.mail.data.vo</value>
      </list>
    </property>

</bean>
```

The LoginServlet file looks like this:

```
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -776218596462464850L;
private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(LoginServlet.class);
private static final int HEX_FF = 0xFF;

/** 
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 * @param response der HttpResponse
 * @param request der HttpRequest
 * @throws ServletException ex
 * @throws IOException ex
 */
@Override
@Transactional
protected void doPost(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


    if (!"Registrieren".equals(request.getParameter("register"))) {

        final SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        final Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();

        // Generiert einen HashWert aus dem eingegebenen Passwort
        try {
            final byte[] pwBytes = request.getParameter("password").getBytes();
            final MessageDigest algorithm = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            algorithm.reset();
            algorithm.update(pwBytes);
            final byte[] messageDigest = algorithm.digest();

            final StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();

            for (byte digest : messageDigest) {
                hexString.append(Integer.toHexString(HEX_FF & digest));
            }

            final LoginDAO dao = new LoginDAO();
            final List<UserVO> list = dao.checkLogin(request, session);

            final UserVO userVO = list.get(0);

            if (userVO.getPassword().equals(hexString.toString())) {

                request.getSession().setAttribute("userid", userVO.getId());
                final RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("main.jsp");
                dispatcher.forward(request, response);

            } else {

                final RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp");
                dispatcher.forward(request, response);
            }

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException nsax) {
            LOG.debug("Keine MessageDigestSpi fuer den entsprechenden Alogrithmus gefunden");

        } catch (NullPointerException npx) {
            final RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);

        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ioobx) {
            final RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        }
    } else {
        final RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("register.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
}

/** 
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 * @param response der HttpResponse
 * @param request der HttpRequest
 * @throws ServletException ex
 * @throws IOException ex
 */
@Override
protected void doGet(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(request, response);
}

}
```

HibernateUtil:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public final class HibernateUtil {

private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
private static final String CONFIG_FILE = "hibernate.cfg.xml";

/**
 * Standardkonstruktor
 */
private HibernateUtil() {
    // TO AVOID CREATION OF UTILITY-CLASS
}

static {
    URL url = Hibernate.class.getClassLoader().getResource(CONFIG_FILE);
    Configuration cfg = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure(url);
    sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
}

/**
 * 
 * @return ret
 */
public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

/**
 * Ã–ffnet eine Session
 * 
 * @return die geÃ¶ffnete Session
 * @throws HibernateException
 *             hex
 */
public static Session getSession() throws HibernateException {
    return HibernateUtil.sessionFactory.openSession();
}

/**
 * HibernateUtil.java SchlieÃŸt alle DB-Verbindungen und alle Caches
 */
public void shutdown() {
    HibernateUtil.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().close();
    HibernateUtil.sessionFactory.close();
}

}
```

I know my code isn't the best, but I'm fairly new to spring and its a very old project in which I had to implement spring.

I face literally no idea what exactly causes the error. I've searched the whole web for days now... If someone has a suggestion or better a solution to this I would be pretty happy.

Comment: You should also `HibernateUtil`. It shows up in the stacktrace. Also from the code and stacktrace, it seems that Spring is not coming into play anywhere

Comment: Yeah, you might be right. I will look into this right now.

Comment: I'm just wondering, spring seems to be initialized correctly: **Information: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext** - do I miss something in my context.xml?

Comment: The way you are using Hibernate from the Servlet, causes Spring to not come into play. You are using some `HibernateUtil` that should be doing something with Hibernate, but probably doesn't use Spring correctly or at all. The log info you mention just says that Spring was initialized, nothing else

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I will have to look into this on monday. Have a nice weekend!

Comment: You too! Hope you resolve your issue!

Comment: I think I see my problem here. But know I can't do anything. Have to wait till monday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I looked into the code after the weekend the solution was right there...

The problem was obviously the **HibernateUtil**:

```
private static final String CONFIG_FILE = "hibernate.cfg.xml";
```

pretty fail I guess, when trying to configure hibernate via **context.xml** :P